# Regular expression to only allow whole numbers and commas in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Does anyone know what the preg_replace would be for a string to only allow whole numbers and commas? I want to strip all whitespace, letters, symbols, etc, so all that is left is numbers and commas, but without any leading or training commas in the string. (Example: 5,7,12)

Here is what I am using now and it only strips whitespace before and after the commas but allows anything else, I think.

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('|\\s*(?:' . preg_quote($delimiter) . ')\\s*|', $delimiter, $str));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
$str = preg_replace(
  array(
    '/[^\d,]/',    // Matches anything that's not a comma or number.
    '/(?<=,),+/',  // Matches consecutive commas.
    '/^,+/',       // Matches leading commas.
    '/,+$/'        // Matches trailing commas.
  ),
  '',              // Remove all matched substrings.
  $str
);
```

Comment: This works perfect except that it doesn't remove matching numbers after the spaces and other things are removed, if that is what you meant for the last line. (Example: ,  3,,,,,    ,     2     4           ,    ,  3   , 2    4    ,,,,,) returnes 3,24,3,24)

Comment: I want to think there is a nicer way to do this, but I cannot seem to thing of anything.

Comment: I can use array_unique to catch the dupes, so this should do the job. Thank you very much for the quick answer.

Comment: Brook, what does the second comma (after the bracket and before the +) do in this line? '/(?<=,),+/',  // Matches consecutive commas.

Comment: @Rob `(?<=` is a lookbehind.  It is used to qualify a match without including the qualifier in the match itself.  In the code above, it is used to consolidate consecutive commas, so any commas that appear immediately after another comma will be replaced by '' (but the first comma will be left alone).

Comment: Thanks, Phoenix, for the explanation. Hopefully one of these days I will understand regex a little better. And thanks for the fix above.

Comment: @Boofo This site is a great reference:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to your question:

```
//drop all characters except digits and commas
    preg_match_all('/[\\d,]/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $result = implode('', $result[0]);

//strip the empty or trailing commas
    if( preg_match('/^,*(\\d.*?\\d),*$/', $result, $regs) ){
        $result = $regs[1];
    }
```

But you might want to use this function instead?

Sounds like a function I once wrote.  See: https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Validation/Arrays.php

```
/**
* Ensures that the input is an array or a CSV string representing an array.
* If it's a CSV string, it converts it into an array with the elements split 
* at the comma delimeter.  This method removes empty values. 
* 
* Each value must be a postitive integer.  Throws and exception if they aren't
* (doesn't throw on empty value, just removes it).  This method will santize
* the values; so, if they're a string "2", they'll be converted to int 2.
* 
* 
* Eg.
*     sanitizeCsvArrayPostitiveInteger( '1,2,,,,3' );   //returns array( 1, 2, 3 );
*     sanitizeCsvArrayPostitiveInteger( array( 1, 2, 3 ) );   //returns array( 1, 2, 3 );
*     sanitizeCsvArrayPostitiveInteger( array( 1, "hello", 3 ) );   //throws Exception
*     sanitizeCsvArrayPostitiveInteger( '1,2,,"hello",,3' );   //throws Exception
* 
* @param mixed $input
* @throws Exception //if $input is not null, a string or an array
* @throws Exception //if $input contains elements that are not integers (or castable as integers)
* @return array
*/
static public function sanitizeCsvArrayPostitiveInteger( $input );
```

Comment: PS. I highly recommend http://www.regexbuddy.com/ for quickly creating and testing regex patterns. It even writes the PHP code for you.

Comment: You can suppress the exception by wrapping it in a try catch block.

Comment: If it doesn't strip the everything except integers and commas, then that wouldn't work for what I need it for. But I thank you very much for responding. You guys are great here! ;)

Comment: How about the code above that function? That strips all of the characters except digits and commas. Could you provide some samples of expected input and output please? :-)

Comment: Yes, sir, I can. I know this is far-fetched but there are those that will try to defeat this. They would try something like this for example: ,  (3,,,,,    ,     2   hello?  4           , what is going on?   ,  3   , 2  !@#$%^  4    ,,,,, ), sans the brackets. That should end up as 3,24. There might be more numbers is the setting, but that is the gist of the idea. I'm not sure how else to show it in the comment box here. I need it to only show like 3,24,56,75,5 etc. Sorry if it sounds confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't really what you where looking for but it returns the string formatted correctly everything time I have tried it.

```
$string = ", 3,,,,, , 2 4 , , 3 , 2 4 ,,,,,";
//remove spaces
$string = preg_replace("[\s]","",$string);
// remove commas
$array = array_filter(explode(",",$string));
// reassemble
$string = implode(",",$array);

print_r($string);
```

returns `3,24,3,24`

Comment: Your first code works fine for anything other than commas or numbers. But thos code wonlt work as the 2 4 are one number not separate. So, it should be: 3,24,3,24. Anything other than a comma (or whatever delimiter you chose) and numbers, should be stripped.

Comment: I have changed the code, and it will now remove the spaces and group the numbers while still maintaining the separation you are wanting. If you want to make it more dynamic just replace the `","` with a variable or the delimiter of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a the function I came up with, with everyone's help. It works fine for commas, but not any other delimiters.

```
if (!function_exists('explode_trim_all')) {
  function explode_trim_all($str, $delimiter = ',') {
    if ( is_string($delimiter) ) {
      $str = preg_replace(
        array(
          '/[^\d'.$delimiter.']/', // Matches anything that's not a delimiter or number.
          '/(?<='.$delimiter.')'.$delimiter.'+/', // Matches consecutive delimiters.
          '/^'.$delimiter.'+/',                   // Matches leading delimiters.
          '/'.$delimiter.'+$/'                    // Matches trailing delimiters.
        ),
        '',              // Remove all matched substrings.
        $str
      );
      return explode($delimiter, $str);
    }
    return $str;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you change `'/(?<='.$delimiter.'),+/'` to `'/(?<='.$delimiter.')'.$delimiter.'+/'` this would work or any other delimiter you wanted.