# Regex of numbers and commas in correct fomat for PHP app

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex for my php app that confirms that the user entered text in the format of numbers separated with commas.  For example:

```
1,2
1,2,3
6,4,5,3,2,1
```

There can be no other characters but numbers and commas.

Thank you,
Mark

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5798129/212218

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regular expression should do it: `(\d+,)*\d+`.

**Explanation:**

```
\d+             One or more consecutive digits
\d+,            ...followed by a comma
(\d+,)*         ...and all of the above repeated zero or more times
(\d+,)*\d+      ...and finally ending with one or more digits
```

This expression will not allow an "extra" comma after the last number, or before the first number, or multiple consecutive commas.

Comment: PHP gives me Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '*' in ....

Comment: @user390480: The regex for `preg_match` and co. needs to be sandwiched between two identical characters (your choice, but `/` is commonly used) and properly escaped. For example: `preg_match('/(\\d+,)*\\d+/', ...)`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the regular expression you are looking for: `\d+(,\d+)*`.

It has the advantage of matching a single number without a comma, or a comma-separated list of numbers with no trailing comma.

Comment: How is this any different from the previous answer?

Comment: It's not. I'm fairly certain I wrote the above answer before seeing the currently accepted answer. This was ~6 years ago so I don't remember much.