# need a regexp to match positive integers separated by commas

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to only allow whole numbers and commas in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798129/regular-expression-to-only-allow-whole-numbers-and-commas-in-a-string)

I need a regexp to match a sequence of POSITIVE integers separated by comma. Space is also allowed.

For example

`706101`, `700102`, `700295` should match, but `0, 1, 2, 3` should not.

I tried to use   `/^\s*(\d+(\s*,\s*\d+)*)?\s*$/`   but it seems to accept zeros as well.

Comment: Define what a "sequence" is. Should there be a minimum and maximum number of digits?

Comment: 1, 2, and 3 are all positive numbers so I don't think "positive" is the right word to describe what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work. The main change is basically switching from `\d` ([0-9]) to `[1-9]`.

This regex also allows you to type digits such as `0001`.

`/^(?:0*[1-9]\d*\s*(?:,|$)\s*)+$/gm`

As you have not specified language, the flags may change. This is PCRE.

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/kN2tW0

Comment: As advised I replaced the \d+ with [1-9]\d* so my final string is /^\s*([1-9]\d*(\s*,\s*[1-9]\d*)*)?\s*$/. The language is javascript.

Comment: Thanks for demo and explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Replace `(\d+)` with `[1-9]\d*` and it gonna work. For example:

```
/^\s*[1-9]\d*(?:\s*,\s*[1-9]\d*)*$/
```

This regex will fail at empty string (while the one in the original post won't), but I assume it's actually the intention. If not, just make the first 'number part' optional.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[1-9][0-9]+( *, *[1-9][0-9]+)*
```

Comment: What about the space after commas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`^([1-9]\d*[\s,]*)+$`

This RE will completely elliminate strings with standalone '0' at any place in the string.